# how to program factoranalysis iterations

Tags: r

Currently i'm very busy with a new type of factor analysis. I created the following binary operators:

1. %M%     calculates a square positive definite symmetric matrix from an R dataframe
2. %E%     calculates communality estimates and places these on the main diagonal of the square matrix M
3. %F%    extracts one factor at a time from the new square matrix
4. %R%   reproduce a new square matrix from the factor loadings of %F% and subtracts it from the original matrix

This is one cycle. The steps 2 to 4 are duplicated for the residuals,%F% extracts a second factor,    %R%    reproduces a new matrix, etc. 
In this fashion the complete procedure (steps 2 - 4 , 2 - 4) is successively applied to smaller and smaller matrices.

My question is: How can i program these iterations in R? Clearly, in each iteration Step 4 is input for a new cycle from step 2 to step 4 in the next iteration.

Some R - code I use:

## iterations

```
res=  a%M%lg3
est=  res%E%5
F1=   est%F%1

res=  F1%R%est
est=  res%E%5
F2=   est%F%1
res=   F2%R%est

est=  res%E%5
F3=   est%F%1
res=  F3%R%est
```

a= is an R dataframe, lg3 is new bivariate log3 consensus coefficient.

I welcome this opportunity to ask for some help.

Regards,

Luc

Comment: Can you add your data and function definitions please?

Comment: I am very curious about your new type of factor analysis. Can we read somewhere about it? I guess it also helps answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `while` loop, I think:

```
while(..some stopping criteria..) {
  est <- res %E% 5
  res <- est %F% 1 %R% est
}
```

If you wanted to run it just four times, just add a counter

```
for(i in 1:4) {
  est <- res %E% 5
  res <- est %F% 1 %R% est
}
```